# What's the difference between "проглянуть" and "проглянуться"?

Tags: лексикон

According to my dictionary, both проглянуть and проглянуться mean to "peep out". For example:

- Солнце проглянуло из-за облаков
- Солнце проглянулось из-за облаков

Is there a difference?

Comment: The only technical difference here would be that verbs ending with "-ся" give additional indication about the subject acting towards themselves, as that ending adds meaning close to "себя" the the verb. So, second sentence would mean something like "The Sun peeped itself from behind the clouds", while first sentence would not have the word "itself" in it. I'd say that in this particular case, the latter sentence, while technically valid, is not how a native speaker would talk - former sentence is.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

There's no difference other than `проглянуло` is used more frequently. My guess would be that `проглянулось` co-exists because of `показаться` (which is by the way more popular than both `проглянуться` and `проглянуть`), like in phrase:

> Солнце показалось из облаков.

In this context `показаться` can be only reflexive, so `показать` would be an error.

[image]